# RegEx dd/MM/yyyy also accepts dd/MM/yy

Tags: regex

I have this regular expressions which should only accept dates in the format dd/MM/yyyy but it also accepts dates in the form of dd/MM/yy. I found this expression in a post here, they said it also accounts for leap years, different days in months, ...

What do I need to change so it works as it should?

```
^(?:(?:31(\/)(?:0?[13578]|1[02]))\1|(?:(?:29|30)(\/)(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2])\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|^(?:29(\/)0?2\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])(\/)(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$
```

Could anyone please help?

Kind regards

Comment: Wow... i'm pretty sure you can find a simpler regex.
[Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Jamie_Zawinski)

Comment: I would recommend a simple regex to check the *format* only, and check the *validity* (i.e., does this date exist at all) using some Date class of your programming language.

Comment: @EvanKnowles I haven't tried anything yet because I don't really understand the expression :-/

Comment: @DaniëlKnippers I'm using SoftwareAG for this application so I'm not really using a programming language i.e. I don't have access to the Java code (I'm just an intern)

Comment: @user2202925, if you don't understand the expression, I recommend you don't use it.  Relying on something you can't debug yourself is a recipe for disaster.  Follow Daniël's advice and check format and validity separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this:

```
(^(((0[1-9]|[12][0-8])[\/](0[1-9]|1[012]))|((29|30|31)[\/](0[13578]|1[02]))|((29|30)[\/](0[4,6,9]|11)))[\/](19|[2-9][0-9])\d\d$)|(^29[\/]02[\/](19|[2-9][0-9])(00|04|08|12|16|20|24|28|32|36|40|44|48|52|56|60|64|68|72|76|80|84|88|92|96)$)
```

Test it [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html)