# Regex Expression is missing a day for dd/MM/yyyy

Tags: regex, date

This regular expression (posted on here as an answer) is supposed to handle dd/MM/yyyy with leap years included but it doesn't handle day 19 for some reason.

What is needs to be changed to fix this?

```
(^(((0[1-9]|[12][0-8])[\/](0[1-9]|1[012]))|((29|30|31)[\/](0[13578]|1[02]))|((29|30)[\/](0[4,6,9]|11)))[\/](19|[2-9][0-9])\d\d$)|(^29[\/]02[\/](19|[2-9][0-9])(00|04|08|12|16|20|24|28|32|36|40|44|48|52|56|60|64|68|72|76|80|84|88|92|96)$)
```

Comment: And where is *here*? :) Please add a link.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23806969/regex-dd-mm-yyyy-also-accepts-dd-mm-yy

Answer (score 2):

Fixed it for you

Changed `"[12][0-8]"` <-- doesn't include 19 to `"1[0-9]|2[0-8]"`

```
"(^(((0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8])[\/](0[1-9]|1[012]))|((29|30|31)[\/](0[13578]|1[02]))|((29|30)[\/](0[4,6,9]|11)))[\/](19|[2-9][0-9])\d\d$)|(^29[\/]02[\/](19|[2-9][0-9])(00|04|08|12|16|20|24|28|32|36|40|44|48|52|56|60|64|68|72|76|80|84|88|92|96)$)"
```

Comment: I'm not judging the Regex, just fixing his problem. I'm not here to re-write that Regex string because i personally would

Comment: Well, looking at [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year#Algorithm) years ending with 00 are only leap years if they are also divisible by 400... as far as I can see this is not checked for. But you're right, this is not your job, the fix you provide nicely solves OP's problem.

Comment: True, people in the year 2300 will not be able to get this date validated with the above: 29/02/2300

Comment: @user2568374 They will, and that is the problem, because they shouldn't. Neither the people from 2100 or 2200. Depending on your use-case this might bother you... just insert  
`(?<=20|24|28|32|36|40|44|48|52|56|60|64|68|72|76|80|84|88|92|96)` before the 00 and it will do it right ;).

Answer (score 0):

I found this one validates 2320 and 3000 as non leap years correctly.

```
^(((0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\/(0[13578]|1[02])\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)\/(0[13456789]|1[012])\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])\/02\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|(29\/02\/((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$
```